# Get the file name from complete path in log4j2 xml

Tags: xml, logging, log4j, log4j2

In my log4j2.xml file, I get the complete path of the logfile by passing a system property

> -Dlogfilename=/home/user/logs/server

Log4j2 configuration:

```
<Property name="logFile">${sys:logfilename:-/home/user/logs/server}</Property>
```

As an added requirement, I need to get the name of the log file from the above property and I cannot pass a new system property. How can I get just the name of the file from the complete path? I dont have any experience with XML other than its use for data transport.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the [System Properties Lookup](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/lookups.html#SystemPropertiesLookup) incorrectly. You should specify the lookup and the key you wish to look up like this: `${sys:logfilename}`

Here's a simple example:

```
package example;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;


public class SomeClass {

    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();

    public static void main(String[] args){
        log.info("Here's some info!");
    }
}
```

Here is the log4j2.xml config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <File name="File" fileName="logs/${sys:myProperty}"
            immediateFlush="false" append="false">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="%-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </File>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="File"  />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

When I run this code with the following JVM parameter:

```
-DmyProperty=myFile.log
```

it generates a file with the name "myFile.log" and the file contains the following output:

```
INFO  example.SomeClass - Here's some info!
```